# Firefox extension - popup panel position issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I've have found a bug on an old Firefox extension I wrote.

```
The extension is not build with the new SDK.
I've tested this extension on Firefox v 30 and 29.
```

[image: Pre-Click]

[image: Post-Click]

**The issue:**

When I shrink Firefox, an arrow appears that contain all extensions buttons (like in the screenshot).

When I click on my extension button a popup appears relative to my extension button, instead of being relative to the arrow button.

So far I couldn't find a way to solve it.
What is the right way to write an extension button with popup? (not with SDK)

**The code:**
*browser.xul*

```
<toolbarpalette id="xxx">
    <toolbarbutton id="button-1" pack="start" title="sdsd" tooltiptext="" oncommand="">
        <stack id="button-1-stack" width="19" height="19">
            <!-- icon -->
            <box align="start" pack="start">
                <image id="button-1-image" src="/skin/button1.png" width="19" height="19" />            </box>
            <!-- badge -->
            <box>
                <label id="button-1-badge" control="button-1-image" />
            </box>
        </stack>
        <!-- popup -->
        <panel id="popup_panel" position="after_end" width="1px" height="1px">
            <browser id="popup_browser" flex="1"></browser>
        </panel>
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

**javascript**

```
var browser = document.getElementById("popup_browser");
browser.addProgressListener(myListener);
browser.setAttribute("src", "/skin/popup.html");
```

Comment: Well, that not *technically* a bug, but expected behavior. A panel will open relative to it's anchor element. But it surely is undesired behavior. I cannot over a complete answer, but here are some first hints: Do not rely on the default behavior, but open the panel yourself giving proper anchors. Compute the anchors based on whether stuff is located in the toolbar, hamburger-menu or overflow-popup.

Comment: To "open popup youself" is get the XUL panel element of his popup and then initiate [`openPopup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/openPopup), this page shows that you can pass an anchor element to this `openPopup` function.

Comment: How can I determine if stuff located in the toolbar or overflow-popup?
Blagoh - What is the popup-overflow anchor?